# find() elements in {!v.body}

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, aura-id, find

I'm rendering components in the body of another component:

```
<c:test>
    <input type="text" aura:id="fooBar" />
</c:test>
```

In this `c:test` component I'm trying to access the inner element by it's aura id, but I can't find it:

**c:test**

```
<aura:component >
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.find}" />

    <button onclick="{!c.find}">find</button>
    {!v.body}
</aura:component>
```

**Controller:**

```
find: function(cmp, event, helper) {
    console.log(cmp.find("fooBar"));
}
```

**Result:** (on init, or when I click the button)

> undefined

**Is there a way to access Components inside the own body?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Lightning/Aura Components: component.find().getElement never accessible](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/147140/lightning-aura-components-component-find-getelement-never-accessible)

Comment: @SebastianKessel thanks, I checked it, and it's not. It does also happen, when I do it on a button click, I will update my answer.

Comment: not sure i understand, but, !v.body seems to be empty, unless you are dynamically creating a component with an aura:id fooBar, i am not surprised cmp.find foobar is undefined. what makes you think that adding an HTML tag in within your component tag(s) will be added to the body (is there any documentation on this out of curiosity?)

Comment: @glls the code works fine. `{!v.body}` in that case does exactly what you'd expect. renders whatever was entered between the beginning and end of the tag.

Comment: @glls quoted from the [docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_body.htm) "Any free markup that is not enclosed in one of the tags allowed in a component is assumed to be part of the body and is set in the body attribute."

Comment: thanks! just wanted to know where it is stated that this should work =P. hopefully we can find a way to make this work (will check later today).

Comment: Look at this [answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/133020/20830), it might help.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of problems with this approach.

1. You haven't added the component - you would need to do this dynamically.
2. Component encapsulation means that your find will not work if called from the parent component.

To solve this issue, first add the component dynamically:

```
doInit : function(cmp) {
    $A.createComponent(
        "c:test",
        {"aura:id": "testCmp"},
        function(testCmp, status, errorMessage){
            var body = cmp.get("v.body");
            body.push(newButton);
            cmp.set("v.body", body);
        }
    );
}
```

Then, to perform the find, you will need to define a `method` on the child component that performs the find and executes your action for you.

Eg:

```
cmp.find("testCmp").sampleMethod(arg1, … argN);
```

To define a method, look [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_cmp_methods.htm?search_text=method):